# Create a Java application launcher with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

So I know how to compile a Java project into class files, but I don't know how to run that without Eclipse. I would think that I would have to create a specific Java executable (.jar) that launches from those class files or compile those class files into a Java executable, but I've searched and found nothing on that.

Answer (score 2):

To make a jar launchable, e.g. java -jar fun.jar, you need to add one line to your MANIFEST.MF (which can be done any number of ways):

Main-Class: a.b.c.MainClass

Where a.b.c.MainClass is the name of the Class file containing the main(..) method that should be invoked.

Comment: well done! you're quite right, I should have had a link to begin with. :)  (thanks for adding!)

Comment: The section that will be of the most value to you is "[Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)".

@ebullient No problem. What you had was a good start, so I didn't want to post another full answer. :)

Comment: @LarryK If you are using Maven, there is a [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) for that too ([Example](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/)). For more information, search for the plugin name, "maven-jar-plugin".

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, you can Export to a runnable jar file.  During export, you need to select a run configuration from the Debug Configurations.  If you are running from eclipse, then you already have a run configuration to use.

Beyond that, you might want to look at using 'ant' to package your jar file(s).

Comment: This is what I was doing, and for some reason, there was no configuration for my main class.

Comment: @LarryK Did you specify a main class when you exported it? This is required if you want the .jar to be executable.

Comment: I don't have that option. I have main class and main applet.